# How to virtualize OSX on Linux

Tags: linux, macos, virtualization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to run a MacOSX installation on a virtual machine?](https://superuser.com/questions/16830/is-it-possible-to-run-a-macosx-installation-on-a-virtual-machine)

How can I virtualize OSX on Linux somehow?

I know that the OSX eula states that OSX can only be virtualized on Apple hardware so I guess that's why virtualization for it is so underdeveloped.

I want to do some iPhone development, don't have a mac available.

Comment: This really should be on Superuser.

Comment: If the OS X EULA states that, then you're out of luck, legally, and I doubt very many people here would be willing to help you out the other way.

Comment: This makes me ask myself if I can be bothered heading over to Meta and proposing a "Question seeking help with violating copyright law" close reason.

Comment: duplicity - http://superuser.com/questions/16830/is-it-possible-to-run-a-macosx-installation-on-a-virtual-machine/16832#16832

Comment: Welcome to the internet... It's not like someone here is going to sit with him, and help him COMMIT A CRIME, oh no. Providing links is hardly going to make you accessory to crime.

Comment: In my humble opinion, this is not an exact duplicate since this question refers to Linux whereas the other one refers to windows.

Comment: The question is related to running OSX in a Virtual Machine. Host OS is irrelevant in this case.

Comment: A virtual machine is a regular app running on some OS. My answer is specific to Linux.

Comment: @TFM: even if the OP lives in a jurisdiction where Apple's EULA is enforcable, breaking the terms of the EULA is **NOT** a crime.  at worst, it is a breach of a civil contract - a matter dealt with by civil courts, not criminal courts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use VMWare on Linux -- there are torrents available of a complete OSX install as a VMWare image, though as previous stated that would be a violation of the EULA, copyrights, etc.

It isn't much different than setting up a hackintosh....

Answer (score 3):

It looks like [Ubuntu community](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MacOnLinuxHowto) has an anwser.